# Unable to make sense of the confusion matrix returned by SVM

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, svm

I am trying to understand why the SVM classifier is not able to correctly classify my data. I have presented 10 samples `XX` only out of 2000 samples of my original data. I cannot make sense of the confusion matrix returned by Matlab. I used SVM classifier. Is my code wrong, especially the way I did cross-validation?

`XX` is normalized to `X`, and `Y` is the label. Each feature vector is of length 8.

**Question  **) Can somebody please help how to tackle this issue?

```
             pred 0   pred 1
  actual 0    100       0
  actual 1    100       0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

1. an unbalanced data set (7 and 3 samples),
2. an 8-dimensional feature space and only 7 and 3 samples, which are very much insufficient to fill it (see curse of dimensionality), and
3. you're only using half those samples to train, meaning you're even further away from filling the feature space.

Thus, I am not surprised that the generalization that the SVM came up with is to classify everything as "class 0".

Try using only one of the features (first column of `XX`), and use leave-one-out cross validation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestions and these are the results (1) I used the last 2 features (columns 7 and 8) which gave accuracy of 60% and confusion matrix is ` [100, 0;100, 0] ` (2) changed the crossvalidation to leaveOne out by doing `N = numel(Y);` `part = cvpartition(N,'LeaveOut')`

Comment: but that throws an error `Error using internal.stats.cvpartitionImpl/training (line 189)`
`Requires two input arguments.`

`Error in cvpartition/training (line 209)`
      `  trainIndices = training(cv.Impl,varargin{:});`

`Error in demo_SVM_Modif (line 41)`
`istrain = training(part); % Data for fitting`  I don't know the correct way to do LeaveOut crossvalidation. Can you please help. Thank you